# Javascript match regex against group

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following string:

**Lorem {{ipsum}} dolor {{sit}} amet**

I'm trying to extract thw words *ipsum* and *sit* with the following regex:

```
content = 'Lorem {{ipsum}} dolor {{sit}} amet'
var regexp = /^\\\{\\\{(\w)\\\}\\\}/g;
var match = regexp .exec(content);
```

The match object returns null. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: What makes `{{ipsum}}` different from `{{sit}}`? And what makes `amet` different from `Lorem` and `dolor`?

Comment: @Sumurai8 bot ipsum and sit are captured into `{{` and `}}`. There was a mistake in the question. I'm trying to extract the words ipsum and sit :)

Comment: You only need to double backslashes if you're creating the regep from a string literal, not a regexp literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have WAY too many backslashes, you're only looking for a single word character, and you're only looking for matches right at the beginning of the string.

```
var regexp = /\{\{(\w+)\}\}/g;
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want the two words inside the `{{` and `}}` !! I think that is what he wants but he has a typo but can't be sure.

Comment: @Sniffer He's fixed the typo, he does want the words inside `{{}}`.

Comment: @Kolink Thanks! it seems this works. So I falsely assumed that: `\w` covers whole words instead of only chars and the `\` should be also escaped, thinking which led to `\\\{`